# Marketing Cloud User Settings

Tags: marketing-cloud

Does Marketing cloud automatically disable users if they do not login for 6 months,I have come across this scenario and wanted to confirm.

Comment: Please accept as accepted answer if I have answered your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The user won't get disabled, but the password may expire depending on your security settings for that MID. In Admin settings, there is a section on Password Policy in Security Settings where **User Passwords Expire In** (never expires, 30 days, 60 days, 90 days, or one year).

Answer (score 1):

This feature exists in the Setup > Security > Security Settings of your account:
Login Expires After Inactivity (Never, 30, 60, 90 or 1 year)